# GeoServer in Liferay

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I want to use GeoServer plus OpenLayers in a Liferay portlet. My main question is how to do this? I mean how to include GeoServer in Liferay, how to open GeoServer's admin panel in Liferay.

Next question its how to use default GeoServer's CSS. When I create simple HTML page I use:

```
<link href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

But in Liferay all CSS must be included in file liferay-portlet.xml can someone say how to add this CSS in this file?

Next question: how to use WMS? In HTML I use this:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'cite:filedata', transparent: true, format: "image/png"});
```

I must change this link to WMS to use this in the portlet?

And final question: I try add OpenLayers.js in layfray-portlet.xml but after deploying my portlet I don't see any map controls on the page just an empty DIV.

This is part of liferay-portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
 <portlet-name>MyGreeting</portlet-name>
 <icon>/icon.png</icon>
 <instanceable>true</instanceable>
 <header-portlet-javascript>/js/jquery.min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
 <header-portlet-javascript>/js/OpenLayers.js</header-portlet-javascript>
 <footer-portlet-css>/css/main.css</footer-portlet-css>
 <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
 <css-class-wrapper>MyGreeting-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

TThis is what I get:

[image]

I forget to mention one thing. I see an error in Firebug with this text:

```
localhost:8080/poller/receive error 404 Not Found
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Okay, No w i see the map controls. I add style.css in lifray-portlet.xml and copy directory with images and css from geoserver to lifray css directory. But im still dont know how to use geoserver in liferay.

Comment: Okey, i understand im dummy. To geoserver is work just needed put it in liferay's tomcat directory. Path to WMS still same, nothing need to change.

Comment: You can answer your own question, if you think it worthwhile for others.